# OpenGL Texture DSA not showing texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, opengl-4

I'm attempting to use the newer DSA functions to show textures but it's not working at all.

Here is the code for using the older approach.

```cpp
unsigned int containerTexture = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &containerTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, containerTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

int width = 0, height = 0, channelCount = 0;
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
unsigned char* pixels = stbi_load("res/textures/container.jpg", &width, &height, &channelCount, 0);
if (pixels) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
} else {
    cerr << "Failed to load texture! \n";
}
stbi_image_free(pixels);
```

Here is the DSA version.

```cpp
unsigned int containerTexture = 0;

int width = 0, height = 0, channelCount = 0;
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
unsigned char* pixels = stbi_load("res/textures/container.jpg", &width, &height, &channelCount, 0);
if (pixels) {
    glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &containerTexture);

    glTextureParameteri(containerTexture, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTextureParameteri(containerTexture, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTextureParameteri(containerTexture, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTextureParameteri(containerTexture, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTextureStorage2D(containerTexture, 1, GL_RGB8, width, height);
    glTextureSubImage2D(containerTexture, 1, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    glGenerateTextureMipmap(containerTexture);

    glBindTextureUnit(0, containerTexture);
} else {
    cerr << "Failed to load texture! \n";
}
stbi_image_free(pixels);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to `glTextureSubImage2D` is the `level` to be set. Mipmap levels are zero-based, therefore the base level is `0` and not `1` as in your code:

```
glTextureSubImage2D(containerTexture, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```